# Sort vector of vectors of objects

Tags: c++, sorting, oop, vector, std

I have some vector of vectors like this:

```
vector<vector<Object> > vec;
```

I also have a struct for the `comp`function of `std::sort`

```
struct SortByName {
    bool operator() (Object& o1, Object& o2) {
        return o1.getName() < o2.getName();
    }
} _sortByName;
```

Then I initialize my sort method:

```
void Object::sort_by_name() {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), _sortByName);
}
```

But this did not work out for me.

So, I have two classes. The one class just fills in objects of the other class inside a vector. Then I am making more vectors of the object and push them into the vector of vectors. And then I want to sort the Objects of the vector inside the big vector by name or something else.

Comment: any guess why? please review what you have written.

Comment: Please put some work into your problem description. And once you've got a detailed problem description, provide an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user3653164 `vector<vector<Object>>` is not `vector<Object>`, in case you still don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `vector` that contains `vector`-s. You have also have a function object that can sort `vector`-s that contain `Object`-s. That means your sorting functor can sort `vector<Object>`-s, not `vector<vector<Object>>`-s.

You have to write another functor that is able to sort `vector<vector<Object>>`-s, for example based on their size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
vector<vector<Object>> vec;
```

You can either sort all the nested vectors:

```
for(auto &nested_vec : vec)
    std::sort(nested_vec .begin(), nested_vec .end(), _sortByName);
```

or just one specific nested vector:

```
std::sort(vec[index].begin(), vec[index].end(), _sortByName);
```

That's simple. However, in case you want to perform sorting in between the nested vectors, it will require a more complex algorithm and you should rather question yourself why you chose to use vector of vectors in the first place.